# Android dalvik errors with Cordova 3.7 plugin, Good Dynamics

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cordova, good-dynamics

working on a project running API 19, Cordova 3.7 plugin on Android.

Seeing these messages in logcat but not sure what could be cauing them. I have never seen these kinds of errors in regular Java dev.

Can someone shed some light what some of these errors could mean and how I could possible correct them??

Thank you much.
Andrew

```
02-21 16:04:26.891    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite V/StatusBar﹕ StatusBar: initialization
02-21 16:04:26.921    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite V/StatusBar﹕ Executing action: _ready
02-21 16:04:26.971    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/CordovaPlugin﹕ Attempted to send a second callback for ID: StatusBar1065051478
    Result was: "Invalid action"
02-21 16:04:27.201    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 8027 (ENCODING_ERR) in Lorg/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils;
02-21 16:04:27.201    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000d
02-21 16:04:27.221    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 8027 (ENCODING_ERR) in Lorg/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils;
02-21 16:04:27.221    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0014
02-21 16:04:27.241    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 8029 (NOT_FOUND_ERR) in Lorg/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils;
02-21 16:04:27.241    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001b
02-21 16:04:27.251    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve exception class 2741 (Lorg/apache/cordova/file/FileExistsException;)
02-21 16:04:27.261    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x21
02-21 16:04:27.271    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/good/gd/cordova/plugins/storage/GDStoragePluginHandler;.handlePluginMethod (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/json/JSONArray;Lorg/apache/cordova/CallbackContext;)V
02-21 16:04:27.271    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0021
02-21 16:04:27.271    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/good/gd/cordova/plugins/storage/GDStoragePluginHandler;.handlePluginMethod (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/json/JSONArray;Lorg/apache/cordova/CallbackContext;)V
02-21 16:04:27.281    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier rejected class Lcom/good/gd/cordova/plugins/storage/GDStoragePluginHandler;
02-21 16:04:27.281    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/PluginManager﹕ THREAD WARNING: exec() call to GDStorage.getDictionary blocked the main thread for 115ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
02-21 16:04:27.281    1204-1281/com.test.sqlite W/CordovaPlugin﹕ Attempted to send a second callback for ID: GDStorage1065051479
    Result was: "Invalid action"
```